# Capacitor - Filesystem.readFile fails due to missing permission when opening a file with share functionality in my app

Tags: ios, angular, capacitor

I want to open a file in my app using the share functionality (I try to share the file directly from the file system). This is my code in app.module.ts (Angular):

```
    import {Plugins} from '@capacitor/core';
    const {Filesystem} = Plugins;

    App.addListener("appUrlOpen", async (appUrlOpen) =>
    {
       Filesystem.readFile({path: appUrlOpen.url})
         .then((contents) =>
         {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => this.myFileService.importFileFromFileSystem(reader.result as any);
            reader.readAsText(new Blob([atob(contents.data)]));
         }).catch(e => alert(e.errorMessage));
     });
```

Everything works fine except for the error message:

> The file “blablabla” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have
> permission to view it.

the object 'appUrlOpen' looks like this:

```
{
  "iosOpenInPlace":"",
  "iosSourceApplication":"",
  "url":"file:\/\/\/private\/var\/mobile\/Containers\/Shared\/AppGroup\/E7BA70BF-BBAA-4050-9D07-A87E14D4FDEE\/File%20Provider%20Storage\/My%20App%20Name\/MyFolder\/my%20file.territory"
}
```

Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
  <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
  <string>Editor</string>
  <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
  <array>
    <string>Icon-22x29.png</string>
    <string>Icon-44x58.png</string>
    <string>Icon-64x64.png</string>
    <string>Icon-320x320.png</string>
  </array>
  <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
  <string>My App</string>
  <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
  <array>
      <string>territory</string>
  </array>
  <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForType</key>
  <true/>
  <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
  <string>Alternate</string>
  <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
  <array>
    <string>public.data</string>
  </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
```

This works when I open the file directly from an email attachment. But when I click on the file directly and share it to my app, it no longer works. Here the file seems to come from the "File Provider Storage". What do I have to do to make it work?

Comment: Make sure you have the `AppGroups` entitlements added to your Xcode project, since it looks like you're trying to access the `AppGroup` directory.

Comment: I have added the 'app group' capability with a unique identifier for my app but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is already a bit old but I had a very similar issue.

What seems to be the problem is that the @capacitor/filesystem (5.0.2 as of writing) plugin does not call `url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` before and `url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` after loading a file (which seems to be necessary for some directories). See [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/108323) discussion in the apple dev forums or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72287168/the-file-couldn-t-be-opened-because-you-don-t-have-permission-to-view-it-real-d).

Afaik it's not possible to do this through JS/TS.

Until the plugin developers change this, it's possible to edit the plugin yourself at `/filesystem/ios/Plugin/Filesystem.swift`:

```
[...]

public func readFile(at fileUrl: URL, with encoding: String?) throws -> String {
    fileUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    if encoding != nil {
        let data = try String(contentsOf: fileUrl, encoding: .utf8)
        fileUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        return data
    } else {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
        fileUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        return data.base64EncodedString()
    }
}

[...]
```