# The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it (REAL DEVICE)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, csv, permissions

I know that similar questions have been asked but I couldn't find anything that solves my problem.

In my case, I have developed an iOS app (Xcode 13.4) to import and parse data from a CSV file that I pick using an `UIDocumentPickerViewController`. Everything works fine on simulator, but when I run the app on my iPhone, the moment I pick a file and try to parse it, my app crashes with the error `The file "test.csv" couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it`. I have added every permission that are related with documents access in my `Info.plist` as follows:

```
<key>NSFileProviderDomainUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Description</string>
    <key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSDesktopFolderUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSDownloadsFolderUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSFileProviderPresenceUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSDocumentsFolderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Description</string>
    <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
    <true/>
```

But nothing works. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In case someone is interested, I've been able to solve it by calling url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() in the document picker before actually accessing the file. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your "In case someone is interested", just turned into a huge win for me.  Thanks for taking the time to post your solution!

Comment: @cdeerinck I’m so glad it helped. Have a nice day!

Comment: I was able to access files on the simulator but failed to do so on a real iPhone. This solved my problem, thanks Carlos!